# ExtJS GridPanel add another parameter to querystring

Tags: javascript, grid, extjs

I have a Grid and some options outside of the grid... my proxy is a POST Request to an ASPX page.

```
_store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
            url: 'resultpage.aspx?initalparam=1...',
            method: "POST"
        }),
        reader: _reader,...
```

What I want, it's when any of my options is selected, add that option as query string parameter (or post parameter) and made the post request.

REF: http://www.objis.com/formationextjs/lib/extjs-4.0.0/docs/api/Ext.grid.Panel.html

Note: the fallowing code DOESN'T Work is just ideas.***********************

I am looking for something like:

```
myoption=...; //with DOM get option value
myurl = panelobj.getGrid().getStore().getProxy().getUrl();
panelobj.getGrid().getStore().getProxy().setUrl(myurl+"&myoption=" + myoption);
panelobj.Update();
```

or something more cool like:

```
Ext.create('...ON OPTION CLICK...', append("&myoption=" + myoption); submit();..)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see this example http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?9067-Ext.data.HttpProxy-and-extraParams. Assume that ds is datastore:

```
ds.proxy.getConnection().request({extraParams: { testParam2: 200 }, method: 'POST',url: ds.proxy.buildUrl()});
```

That make the request but in the server side I can't read `testParam2`. `Request["testParam2"]` is null

That way wasn't working for me (I use version 3) so I using `params` instead of `extraParams` http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.data.Connection (Form Parameter: POST)

```
ds.proxy.getConnection().request({params: { testParam2: 200 }, method: 'POST',url: ds.proxy.buildUrl()});
```

other possibility is passing by url (QueryString Parameter: GET)

```
ds.proxy.getConnection().request(method: 'POST',url: ds.proxy.buildUrl() + '&testParam2=200'});
```

//*********************** 
Other Problem:

With the code above, I can made the request... but it's totally independent from the grid... the data that is retrieve is unhandled... how make the grid do the request????? I don't know....

//**********************
Solution:

Remove previous grid and add new one with new parameters! that work for me!

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this? http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Ajax-cfg-extraParams

Each proxy has an extra parameters which can be added to each request.

Comment: I am looking for 2 things: 1. Add an extra parameter (I'm looking into what you mentioned) and 2. Make the request.